# How to find the exact mainline kernel version used in debian 6

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, version

In debian 6 `uname -a` returns `Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686 ...` and `cat /proc/version` shows `Linux version 2.6.32-5-686 ...` but in [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/) theres no `linux-2.6.32-5-686.tar.gz` instead there are `linux-2.6.32.{1-27}.tar.gz` versions. Which one of these did debian use to make the debian kernel?

When you do `aptitude install linux-source-2.6` do you get the vanilla kernel or do you get the kernel with debian patches applied?
I've noticed that on debian 6 `make oldconfig` will configure the kernel source that you get through apt with no additional configurations but configuring the sources from kernel.org via `make oldconfig` needs additional options.

What is the difference between the kernel source provided by debian via `apt` and the mainline kernel in [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/).

Comment: I recommend you to check out http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/.